# Copying a vector reference to another

Tags: c++, vector, reference, copy, structure

I've a structure, say SubscriptionData. Two variables of the type are declared in function 1.

```
SubscriptionData aSubscriptionData;
SubscriptionData aResultSubscriptionData;
```

The structure in itself has another structure, which in turn has a vector of another structure. The vector is given below

```
aSubscriptionData.apn_config_file.apn_config
```

I've initialized the structures properly. Now, I call a function to populate aSubscriptionData. Then I call another function whose prototype is given below.

```
void breakSubDataLen(ImsMsg::SubscriptionData& aSubscriptionData, ImsMsg::SubscriptionData& aResultSubscriptionData);
```

In the function breakSubDataLen(), I'm supposed to copy the elements from aSubscriptionData.begin()+3 to aSubscriptionData.end() to the structure aResultSubscriptionData.

I'm doing the following operation for that.

```
std::copy(aSubscriptionData.apn_config_file.apn_config.begin() + 3, 
    aSubscriptionData.apn_config_file.apn_config.end(),
    aResultSubscriptionData.apn_config_file.apn_config.begin());
```

It doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I'm sorry for the wrong code snippet there. The actual line is std::copy(aSubscriptionData.apn_config_file.apn_config.begin()+3, aSubscriptionData.apn_config_file.apn_config.end(), aResultSubscriptionData.apn_config_file.apn_config.begin());

Comment: Fixed it for you.  BTW, `apn_config` is a `std::vector`, right?

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" is a vague problem description.

Comment: Yes.. apn_config is a std::vector. I'm trying your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::copy` doesn't allocate elements; you have to make sure there is sufficient space in the destination range to hold all of the elements in the source range.

A common way to do this is to use `std::back_inserter`, which calls `push_back` to insert each element into a container:

```
std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(destination));
```

Another common approach is to preallocate sufficient space in the destination sequence using `resize`:

```
destination.resize(std::distance(source.begin(), source.end()));
std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), destination.begin());
```

These two approaches have different behavior, of course.  With `std::back_inserter`, any elements in the sequence are retained and new elements are inserted after the existing elements.  With the `resize` approach, any existing elements are overwritten.  You can also use the `resize` approach and retain any existing elements:

```
const std::size_t original_size = destination.size();
destination.resize(destination.size() + 
                   std::distance(source.begin(), source.end());

std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), destination.begin() + original_size);
```

(This requires that `destination` is a random accessible container like `std::vector`; if it isn't, you'll have to modify the code accordingly.)

Comment: The `resize` approach also iterates through the input twice, which might matter if iterating has side effects like consuming data from a non-seeking file.

Comment: @Mike:  Yes, it does; the source iterator would need to be a ForwardIterator (since the OP has a container, it's all but certain that the source range is forward iterable).

Comment: Shouldn't vector's range insertion function do essentially this, and more efficiently?

Comment: @JaredC:  Yes, that's definitely cleaner (+1), but I'm not certain it would be more efficiently.  If the source is an InputIterator range, the vector either needs to use the `back_inserter` approach or it needs to accumulate into auxiliary storage and then use the resize approach (I'm not 100% certain that this approach would be strictly allowed).  If the source is a ForwardIterator range, it can use the resize approach directly.

Comment: The efficiency question is an interesting one because Standard Library implementers optimize for what they think are the "common case."  I'm in the process of writing a lexer generator right now and it has a transform iterator that converts a character sequence into a token sequence.  The actual tokenization process is relatively expensive, so it's best to only do it once.  With the Visual C++ implementation of `std::vector`, if I use `insert(...)` with my ForwardIterator, it performs tokenization twice:  once in a call to `std::distance` to compute the number of elements in the sequence, and

Comment: (continued) once to copy the elements into the vector (it uses the computed distance to resize the container).  It's actually significantly faster for me to use the `back_inserter` approach (almost twice as fast).  If I changed the iterator category to InputIterator, it uses the `back_inserter` method in the call to `insert`, so I get the "twice as fast" performance as well.  Suffice to say, it's interesting to play with this sort of thing.  Without a good profiler, I'd never have guessed that there would be such a performance difference.

Comment: @James: That's very interesting.  I would have guessed that `insert()` could tell the source range was from a vector and be highly optimized. On second thought though, I'm not sure how it could tell that.

Answer (score 3):

By passing `aResultSubscriptionData.apn_config_file.apn_config.begin()` as the third argument to `std::copy`, you are telling it that you have allocated enough space for it to *assign* the elements starting at `.begin()`.  If the vector has 0 elements in it, then clearly `.begin()` or `.begin() + X` does not refer to valid iterator.  This would work if the vector already held enough elements, or if it was resized, in which case it would copy the elements into the new vector.

More than likely, what you want to use is to use `vector`s range insertion.  It will be much more efficient I believe:

```
aResultSubscriptionData.apn_config_file.apn_config.insert(0, aSubscriptionData.apn_config_file.apn_config.begin() + 3, aSubscriptionData.apn_config_file.apn_config.end());
```